# azure-devops pipeline:unable to recognize "/abc.yml": Get http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-aks

I am trying to deploy my services on AKS using Azure Devops pipeline. Everything works fine except for applying my latest build on Kubernetes service. I am using following command to deploy the service.

```
#- script: docker build -f ./ContainerApp/Dockerfile -t $(dockerServer)/$(imageName) . 
#  displayName: 'Container Build'
#
#- script: docker login -u $(dockerId) -p $(dockerPassword) $(dockerServer)
#  displayName: 'Container Service login'
#
#- script: docker push $(dockerServer)/$(imageName)
#  displayName: 'Container Push'
#
    - script: kubectl apply -f ./azure-kubernetes-deployment.yml
      displayName: 'deploying to Kubernetes'
```

It works fine when i run this command from my local machine, but doesn't work on pipeline. when i run on pipeline following error occures.

can anyone suggest what command i am missing?

```js
2018-11-28T14:19:09.6975888Z Generating script.
2018-11-28T14:19:09.6998755Z Script contents:
2018-11-28T14:19:09.6999302Z kubectl apply -f ./azure-kubernetes-deployment.yaml
2018-11-28T14:19:09.7032788Z [command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/e571ec91-5ac4-4e17-8f48-cd0fd0877683.sh
2018-11-28T14:19:10.0021936Z unable to recognize "./azure-kubernetes-deployment.yaml": Get http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
2018-11-28T14:19:10.0023429Z unable to recognize "./azure-kubernetes-deployment.yaml": Get http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
2018-11-28T14:19:10.0162142Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
2018-11-28T14:19:10.0177080Z ##[section]Finishing: deploying to Kubernetes
```

Comment: Paths are relative to $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory). Are you sure that is where azure-kubernetes-deployment.yaml is placed?

Comment: @ColinB I have verified that by adding additional script 'ls -l', it shows that the script is on the perfect place.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know the reason for it in your particular use case, but

```
unable to recognize "...yaml": Get http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
```

(a rather unhelpful and confusing message) indicates failure to contact the kubernetes cluster.